# Stack Overflow showing less jobs based on IP address / location

Tags: support, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

I am a bit confused: I am currently in New Zealand and looking for jobs in Vienna. When I use my Kiwi computer I get the following result (Image 1) when I look for a Job in Vienna (4 Jobs).
However, when I use a VPN and beam myself to Europe (digitally), I get 65 jobs displayed in total (Image 2).
Now I wonder if Stack Overflow is intentionally limiting the displays per continent/ IP address from other places? Why does Stack Overflow do that?

Image 1:
[image: Stack Overflow jobs from NZ]

Image 2:
[image: Stack Overflow jobs from Europe]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Companies have the option to target their job listing to a specific geographical area. We determine that based on your IP address.

If we detect that your physical location is outside the targeted area, the jobs are hidden from search results and advertising.

Comment: Should this be [status-bydesign]?

Comment: That makes more sense.